# python - storing variable number of columns in input data and attributes

Tags: python

We have several sources of online data (numbers):

```
[ source 1 ]
1 52 61 17
1 2 2 12
31 4 42 1


[ source 2 ]

2 52 6 2 1 2
2 37 4 5 4 35
2 3 74 5 93 7
3 83 8 8 65 0

[ source X ]
...
```

As you can see there are different number of columns in each source. What I'd like to do is to read (using the same script for all data sources) all lines but in a way that let me operate on this numbers (i.e. right align them, underline some of them if they are bigger then Y value, etc). So I need to store also some additional attributes about each number. What would be the best data structure to store these data + attributes about them  ?

UPDATE:
Since some says that the solution depends on what I want to do with these numbers I'll try to explain better:

  * I want to compare them to the values from previous line but from the same column
  * if they differ a lot (a lot = to define by myself) I'd like to log that and print them in a specific formatting (they are going to be printed on a console)
  * if they are over/below some specific value I will log which column, adjust aligning etc  to line them up

Comment: "*underline*" - how should it look like?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: There are myriad options, depending on what you want to do with your data: lists, Numpy, SQL, ...

Comment: actually.. you can use simple data structures like tuples, dict with little complexity and get your job done.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this (pure Python):

```
rows = []
for source in list_of_filenames:
    with open(source) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line == '' or line.isspace():
                continue
            rows.append([(int(num), {}) for num in line.split()])
```

This will give you a list of lists of tuples. Each tuple will contain a number and a dictionary, where you can store metadata.

Answer (score 1):

A custom data structure by using basic python data structures

This is how the data (along with meta values) is:

- There many be several lines in file. So, we assign each line with a name. Say `line1`
- Each line will have several numbers and each will have some attributes.

Now,

1. We construct a `list` in which there are as many `tuples` as number of lines in file.
2. Each tuple's first element is `TupleName` and second element is a `list` which stores numbers data
3. In second element, there are as many tuples as numbers in a row. Where each tuple comprises `number` and `dict` of attributes.

Example :

```
data_structure = [ ("line1", [ ("num1", {"attr1" : value, "attr2" : value, } ),
                               ("num2", {"attr1" : value, } ),
                                ("num3", {} ),
                             ]
                    ),

                    ("line2", [ ("num1", {"attr1" : value, "attr2" : value, } ),
                                ("num2", {"attr1" : value, "attr2" : value, } ),
                            ]
                    ),

                    ("line3", [ ("num1", {"attr1" : value, "attr2" : value, } ),
                    ],
]
```

This one obviously looks complex. However, as we now standardized the data structure, we can write a `class` which defines methods for adding, deleting or editing `attributes` or `numbers` or `lines`. The most important part is, make sure you write a method with creates our data structure from the file object.

Now, you are free from the complexity.

You can use `lists` instead of `tuples` but I just added for sake of not disturbing our defined data structure.

**Sample Class**

*Might be primitive, but it should tell you what I am actually trying to explain*

```
class data (object):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.data = open(self.file_name, "r").readlines()
        # The Data Str
        self.ds = self.makeDS()

    def getNumList(self, line_count):
        return self.data[line_count][:-1].split()

    def makeDS (self):
        ds = []
        for eachLine in self.data:
            line_count = self.data.index(eachLine)
            num_list = self.getNumList(line_count)

            eachLine_num_data = []
            for aNum in num_list:
                num_attr = {}
                eachLine_num_tuple = (aNum, num_attr)
                eachLine_num_data.append(eachLine_num_tuple)
            eachLine_tuple = (line_count, eachLine_num_data)
            ds.append(eachLine_tuple)
        return ds

    def getAttr (self, line_count, num_count):
        attr = self.ds[line_count][1][num_count]
        return attr

    def add_attr (self, line_count, num_count,
                    attr_name, attr_value):
        attr = self.ds[line_count][1][num_count][1]
        attr[attr_name] = attr_value


o = data("file.txt")
o.add_attr(0,0,"name", "value")
print o.getAttr(0, 0)
```

*Output*

```
>>> ('2', {'name': 'value'})
```

**How to apply attributes in file**

This is somewhat complex (not totally). Standard text files doesn't support features like (underline, bold, italic ..). The `.docx` or any other formats are more likely a `zip archive` in `openXML` format. You need to know how to use them in order to apply the about attributes.